# How to group arrays in arraylist by matching a value inside the inner arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains several String[]. I want to loop through the ArrayList and group the inner String[] that contain a matching value. In this case, I'm looking specifically at the second value in the String[] (ex. "CompanyA").

I'm having difficulty understanding what the best logical pattern for this is and how it might be implemented. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```java
List<String[]> attArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String[] entry1 = { "EventOne", "CompanyA", "Matthew" };
String[] entry2= { "EventOne", "CompanyA", "Mary" };
String[] entry3 = { "EventOne", "CompanyB", "Bates" };
String[] entry4 = { "EventOne", "CompanyC", "Carson" };
attArrayList.add(entry1);
attArrayList.add(entry2);
attArrayList.add(entry3);
attArrayList.add(entry4);

for (int i = 0; i < attArrayList.size(); i++) {
  // ...
}
```

My desired result is something like this:

```
[[EventOne, CompanyA, Matthew], [EventOne, CompanyA, Mary]], [EventOne, CompanyB, Bates], [EventOne, CompanyC, Carson]
```

Comment: What does “group the inner String[]“ mean? Your Question is not clear. Your expected output seems to be the same as the input, further confusing me. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @BasilBourque - If you look closer, the desired output shows arrays entry1 & entry2 are in an array together (grouped) while arrays entry3 & entry4 are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String[]>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (String[] strs : attArrayList) {
        if (!map.containsKey(strs[1])) {
            ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(strs);
            map.put(strs[1], list);
        } else {
            map.get(strs[1]).add(strs);
            map.put(strs[1], map.get(strs[1]));
        }
    }
    for (String[] strs : map.get("CompanyA")) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));
    }
```

You can try this.I think it`s easier to understand than using stream(though stream has less code).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would you access the grouped arrays? `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.get("CompanyA")));` only returns one - `[EventOne, CompanyA, Mary]`.

Comment: sorry,I didn`t notice that you were trying to group a String array. I just edited the answer,you can try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupingBy` to group the items based on the second column:

```
Map<String, List<String[]>> groups = attArrayList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(arr -> arr[2]));
```